# Check whether class instance variable with same name as specified function is None or not

Tags: python, function, instance-variables

Given the following class

```
class Household:
    def __init__(self):
         self.dog=None
         self.cat=None
         self.fish=None
    #setter methods
    ...
```

and the following functions **in a separate class**:

```
def dog(...):
    ...
def cat(...):
    ...
def fish(...):
    ...

#animal_function is a function, which can either be dog, cat, or fish
def function(homes, animal_function):
    for home in pets:
        #animal_function.__name__ will evaluate to dog, cat, or fish
        #But Python thinks I'm trying to access home.animal_function, which doesn't exist
        if home.animal_function.__name__ is not None:
            ...
            #Setter method
            home.animal_function.__name__=value
```

Each function (dog, cat, and fish) can only result in a single value given a specific household. So I want to avoid repeated work by first checking if the Household's instance variable with the same name as the parameter function is None or not.

How can I get around the problem I outlined in the comment? Thanks!

Comment: There seems to be an XY problem here, but I can't figure out what you are actually trying to do. What is the relationship between the instance attributes and the functions of the same name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getattr()` to get attributes of an object dynamically (i.e. without knowing the name of the attribute in advance):

```
...
if getattr(home, animal_function.__name__) is not None:
    ...
```

If `animal_function.__name__ == 'cat'`, for example, then `getattr(home, animal_function.__name__)` is equivalent to `home.cat`.

Comment: cool. Did you mean to write 

    if getattr(home, animal_function.__name__)? 

slightly confused on how the .__name__ would be on the outside of that function

Comment: @Anthony I misread your question initially, so yes that is what I meant to write. Makes much more sense that way, thanks. I've edited my answer accordingly.